# Using Remote SSH in VS Code to develope while storing remote code live or timed automatically local?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sftp, rsync, openssh, mirroring

i have a requirement that i have to work on my backend remotely. So i installed OpenSSH client + server and activated on my windows computer the ssh agent and also in the services. Then i used the VS Code extension Remote SHH to establish a ssh connection to navigate, develop and debug the project on remote. Till this point all is fine.

But the next requirement is that the code, written on remote host, should be promptly mirrored/synced to a local path on my computer. I have to store it locally because of possible internet outtakes, backup purposes and because im forced to commit the project to git locally (not on remote).

Using git is not a possibility in that case. I need direct snyc like in rsync or sftp extension in vs code. Using them to snyc data from local to remote works, but i need to sync from remote to local. I tried different approaches named by google, but syncing from linux remote host to local Windows seems not to work.

Du you guys maybe know something what i maybe oversee? Is it possible to install only local extensions or watch processes to inherit automaticly syncing the project to local computer?

Greetings

Comment: `syncthing` might work for this purpose. It's headless and cross platform. There's also rsync/rclone with cron if you can use wsl; you can do deduplicated backups as often as you like.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use Bitvise SSH commands.

sftpc.exe -profile="C:\path\bitviseprofile.tlp" -keypairFile="C:\path\bitvisekey.bkp" cd /home/folder/; get projectfolder "C:\localfolder\projectfolder" -mirror -erase

Only flaw at this point i dont know how to exclude folders with it.